# ¿Que es y para que sirve el operador => en PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, operador, apex

¿alguien me podria explicar como funciona el operador `=>` en **APEX** ó **PL/SQL**?

```
APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
    p_collection_name => LV_COLLECTION_NAME,
    p_c001            => :APP_USER,
    p_c002            => :P1000_START_DATE,
    p_c003            => :P1000_FINISH_DATE,
    p_c004            => UPPER(:P1000_WIP_AREA),
    p_c005            => :P1000_REQUEST_NOTES,
    p_c006            => :P1000_REQUESTED );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Es una manera de pasar parametros a una subrutina PL/SQL llamada **"notacion por nombre"**
- Se usa cuando no conoces el orden en el que deben ir los argumentos de un procedimiento o función, pero si conoces los nombres de cada uno
- Internamente **Oracle** relaciona el nombre de los parametros con el orden correcto